# Using Dalekjs test tool, how to select Option in Dropdown(Select element) when there is no "value" attribute in Option tag?

Tags: javascript, node.js, select, dalekjs

Lets consider below `"Select"` example with `"value"` attribute,

```
<select onchange="fruitSelected();" id="">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="apple">apple</option>
<option value="mango">mango</option>
<option value="banana">banana</option>
</select>
```

Using dalekjs I'm able to select the option using below code,

```
.click('#moduleType option[value="apple"]')
```

But, when the above example don't have `"value"` attribute as show below,

```
<select onchange="fruitSelected();" id="fruitID">
<option></option>
<option>apple</option>
<option>mango</option>
<option>banana</option>
</select>;
```

**How to select option from dropdown?**

I tried using `.execute` as below,

```
.execute(function () {
    document.getElementById("fruitID").selectedIndex = "1";
})
```

I'm able to select option as apple, but onchange function is not getting called.

**How to select option from dropdown? so that onchange function also can b called.**

**NOTE:** Select tag cannot be modified, as I'm just testing.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1):

I did more R&D and found that the above situation can be solved by using `.setvalue()` as below

```
.setValue('#fruitID','apple')
```